# Unexpected behavior with left_join and merge causing NAs

Tags: r

I am trying to merge 2 datasets in R by one column "id" that is in common for both.

I did try using merge and left_join!

```
dataset1
id      var1
KL90    20
KB20    10
KB20    30
KL10    40
KL10    50
KL20    60
KL90    90
KL80    20
KL80    10
```

```
dataset2
id     varA   varB
KL90   2       1.5
KL20   3       1.6
KL10   4       1.7 
KL80   5       1.8
```

I did use merge and left_join by="id"
and I generated this dataset3 below:

```
dataset3
id      var1   varA   varB
KL90    20     2      1.5
KB20    10     3      1.6
KB20    30     NA      NA
KL10    40     4      1.7 
KL10    50     4      1.7 
KL20    60     3      1.6
KL90    90     NA      NA
KL80    20     5      1.8
KL80    10     5      1.8
```

Does someone could help me?
FYI: I converted "id" for characters.
Please, notice that some specific cases it works but for other repetition no.

Comment: Is there whitespace or another not-immediately visible difference between the `KB20` and `KL90` ids in the first dataset? You might run `dataset1 %>% count(id) %>% View()` to see if any lines look similar but aren't quite the same.

Comment: and if you provide the exact structure of your data with `dput(df1)` it would also become unambiguous.

Comment: Generally: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Your output doesn't match what I get or what I would expect. The `id` `KB20` is only found in `dataset1` so it will be filled with `NA` in the `join`ed output.

```r
library(tidyverse)

d1 <- 
  structure(list(id = c("KL90", "KB20", "KB20", "KL10", "KL10", 
                        "KL20", "KL90", "KL80", "KL80"), 
                 var1 = c(20L, 10L, 30L, 40L, 50L, 60L, 90L, 20L, 10L)), 
            class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))

d2 <- 
  structure(list(id = c("KL90", "KL20", "KL10", "KL80"), varA = 2:5, 
                 varB = c(1.5, 1.6, 1.7, 1.8)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                    -4L))
left_join(d1, d2)
#> Joining, by = "id"
#>     id var1 varA varB
#> 1 KL90   20    2  1.5
#> 2 KB20   10   NA   NA
#> 3 KB20   30   NA   NA
#> 4 KL10   40    4  1.7
#> 5 KL10   50    4  1.7
#> 6 KL20   60    3  1.6
#> 7 KL90   90    2  1.5
#> 8 KL80   20    5  1.8
#> 9 KL80   10    5  1.8
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>